# Infinite scroll with useEffect hooks run with previous argument value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-scroll

I implemented the following infinite scroll solution. It's not (yet) optimized for 10K+ items, so thats out of scope for my question.

There are essentially 3 conditions/cases that trigger a `fetchMessage()`:

1. Initial load, no data in the Redux store
2. User scrolls and reaches the 80% of the page height
3. Initial load happens but height is loaded content is not enough to reach 80% of the height / make a scrollbar appear so user scrolling is impossible (therefore we can't see the next page of results)

Questions: What are the standard non-js industry solutions for case (3) (I guess forcing a min-height with CSS)

Bug: `fetchMessage()` is run two times with the same `page` resulting in duplicate data loaded.

```js
const message = useSelector((state) => selectMessages(state)); // returns an array of objects to display
const page = useSelector((state) => selectPage(state)); // returns current page of results
const totalPages = useSelector((state) => selectTotalNumberPages(state)); // returns total number of result pages
const isFetching = useSelector((state) => selectIsFetching(state)); // boolean set to true when a fetch is triggered and to false when its complete

const fetchMessage = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("component page:", page);
    return dispatch(getMessagesIfNeeded(page));
  }, [dispatch, page]);

  const handleScroll = throttle(() => {
    console.log("scrolled");
    let d = document.body;
    let scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    let windowHeight =
      window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    let height = d.offsetHeight - windowHeight;
    let scrollPercentage = scrollTop / height;
    if (scrollPercentage > 0.8) {
      if (!isFetching && page <= totalPages) {
        fetchMessage();
      }
    }
  }, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return function cleanup() {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!message.length) {
      fetchMessage();
    }
  }, [fetchMessage, message]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const d = document.body;
    const bodyHeight = d.offsetHeight;
    let windowHeight =
      window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    if (windowHeight - bodyHeight > 200 && !isFetching && page <= totalPages) {
      fetchMessage();
    }
  }, [isFetching, fetchMessage, page, totalPages]);
```

I also have a working version of the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-noether-npp31?file=/src/message/MessageList.jsx

Comment: I wonder why there is 3 useEffect function?

Comment: Well its easier to read plus the effects are different?

Comment: this is the first example which is using multiple times as a function, so I surprised. Now, I read the documentation, I learned it's possible as separate concern. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns

Comment: sorry for uncompleted comment @George, this was the first example I've ever seen with this way (multiple concern useEffect).